# Disable VSCode counting skipped python tests as Problems?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm experimenting with running pytest tests from within VSCode rather than on the command line.

VSCode seems to list all skipped tests as "Problems", and including this number in its running count of problems. This renders the Problems panel much less useful. Generally skipped tests are not problems.

While it's possible to disable the listing by deselecting "Show Infos" from the filter, the "1K+" remains.

Is there a way to change this? Or should this be a bug report / feature request into VSCode's python extension?

[image: screenshot]